# Salvaging a piclked XGBoostClassifier from older major version

Tags: machine-learning, pickle, xgboost

TL;DR How to import a pickled XGBoost model from an older major version?

---

I trained a XGBoost model using version 0.6 using their scikit-learn API so the classifier is of class `xgboost.XGBClassifier`. I saved that trained model in the pickle format.

However, I need to move my model to an updated version of XGBoost 1.0.

I've tried following their guide on loading/saving model (https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/saving_model.html) but it seems like the old XGBClassifer model doesn't have any of those methods.

What do I do with this trained `xgboost.XGBClassifier` object so I can convert it to be loadable in XGBoost 1.0?

Answer (score 1):

In the old environment (with old `xgboost` version) you load the pickled model normally, then call the hidden `_booster.save_model` method:

```
import pickle as pkl

clf = pkl.load(model,'rb')
clf._booster.save_model('clf.model')
```

Then in the updated environment (here: with `xgboost==1.0`) you load the model using the new `load_model` method:

```
import xgboost as xgb

clf = xgb.XGBoostClassifier()
clf.load_model('clf.model')
```

This relies on the guarantee of backward compatibility of XGBoost models (as opposed to lack thereof for serializations as pickled objects) - see [docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/saving_model.html).